# How to position text and a button in this manner?

Tags: swiftui

This is an example of what I am trying to do.[Link to image of design to implement.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rbTz.png)  I am unsure how to position a button and text at the top of the screen in this manner coding in swiftui. Alternatively I thought I could use the navigation bar inline and customise that but I am unsure.

```
var body: some View {
        VStack (alignment: .trailing) {
            HStack(spacing:10) {
                Button(action: {
                    
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                        .font(.headline)
                }
                Text("WeCollab")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.title)
                    //padding(.leading,40)
                    Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.top,UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top)
            .background(customPurpleColour)
            Spacer()
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're on the right track. In order to keep the title centered, it seemed easier to make a `ZStack`. The menu button gets it's own `.leading`-aligned `VStack` and then the title goes on top of that.

The `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` and `padding` can be simplified so that you don't have to use the screen size safe areas.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: { }) {
                        Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")
                            .font(.headline)
                    }.padding(.leading)
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                
                Text("WeCollab")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.title)
            }
            .background(Color.purple.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top))
            
            Spacer() //other content goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this solved your issue, you can mark it as correct by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to implement a sidebar using the above code. Perhaps because I am a rookie in swift.

Comment: the tutorials on YouTube some do use completely different ways of implementing it, do you mind helping me out or at least directing me to a good video please.

Comment: You'd have to be a little more specific -- there are lots of ways to implement a sidebar. You can see one of my answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66511464/560942 If that doesn't cover it, maybe make another question with what you've tried so far.

Comment: How do you go from one view to another in a side menu bar I created ? [swiftui]

Comment: That sounds like a good opportunity to make a new question to cover that. Like the sidebar, there are many possible ways that might be implemented.